# How do I find the maximum of a certain complex expression?

Tags: complex, maximum

I have this expression:

```
TFilter1 = -(7.5438*10^8/(6.34731*10^8 + 48270.2 s + s^2))
```

where `s` is a complex variable give by $s =  2\pi\,i f$. I want to find the maximum of the absolute value of this function. I tried to do:

```
Max[Abs[TFilter1 /. s -> i 2*pi*f], {f, 10.0, 10^5}]
```

But was unsuccessful. Any guess?

Comment: Use `NMaximize` instead `Max`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TFilter1 = -(7.5438*10^8/(6.34731*10^8 + 48270.2 s + s^2));
Maximize[{Abs[TFilter1 /. s -> I 2*Pi*f], 10.0 <= f <= 10^5}, f]
```

> `{1.1885, {f -> 10.}}`

The function is

```
TFilter1 = -(7.5438*10^8/(6.34731*10^8 + 48270.2 s + s^2));
Plot[Abs[TFilter1 /. s -> I 2*Pi*f], {f, 10, 10^5}, PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that that value is actually wrong, the correct answer is 1.8195 :/ CORRECTION: it should be 2.1625

Comment: Nevermind, you are absolutely right, thank you!